# Do any positive integers in the form $10^k + 1$ have perfect square factors?

Tags: number-theory

I've tried to find a way to prove that any number in the form $10^{k}+1$ doesn't have any perfect square factors. Tried looking for a case where $k$ was even and odd, tried factoring $11$ out of odd $k$ and eventually gave up.

Comment: $11^2\,|\,(10^{11}+1)$...and $7^2\,|\,(10^{21}+1)$.

Comment: thanks, i found a general way of finding these integers

Comment: As a point of curiosity:  Just based on the search I did (not so very extensive), in every instance for which $10^k\equiv -1\pmod {p^2}$ we have $p\,|\,k$.  For instance, the least $k$ for which $17^2$ divides $(10^k+1)$ is $k=136=17\times 8$.  Could be an accident of small numbers, of course.

Comment: @lulu That's likely because $10^{p(p-1) } \equiv 1 \mod{p^2}$, and when we take square roots repeatedly, so $2^z k = p(p-1)$. Since $p$ is odd, thus $ p \mid k$.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Ah!  Thanks.

Comment: It is indeed possible, though rare, for $p$ not to divide $k$; this can occur if $10$ happens to be a $p$th power modulo $p^2$. These are known as (base-10) [Wieferich primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime#Base-a_Wieferich_primes); in this context we need the order of $10$ modulo $p$ to be even as well. For example, $487^2$ divides $10^{243}+1$. (The flaw in @CalvinLin's argument is that $10^{p(p-1)}\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$ implies only that the order must divide $p(p-1)$, not necessarily equal it.)

Answer (score 1):

Like Lulu wrote above, there are several examples that prove there are perfect square factors of these numbers ($11^2$ | $10^{14}$ + 1, etc). If you want to look more into these, they are known as General Fermat Numbers (https://oeis.org/wiki/Generalized_Fermat_numbers) since they are in the form $a^n + b^n = a^n + 1^n = a^n + 1$ where a = 10. There is a lot of additional work done on General Fermat Numbers F(10,1) = F(10) which show the prime factorizations of $10^x + 1$ for large x if you want to look more into that (http://www.prothsearch.com/GFN10.html).